# K-means Clustering: Determine optimal number of centroids based on maximum size of data point in a cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mean, k-means, centroid

I need to find the optimum location and number of centroids for a set of 96 lines. The lines are represented by the distance between two set of start point and end point coordinates in (x,y,z).

Each centroid MUST NOT take more than a maximum of 10 lines. The z component of the centroid coordinates need to be set to zero too. My code as shown below returns the centroid location and assign labels (i.e. lines) to each centroid but some centroids take more than 10 which is not what desired.

Below is the code and the solution of my attempted code:

To solve the problem, I am using k-mean clustering available from Scikit package in python 2.7.

The start point coordinates in x,y,z of the line are shown below:

```
Start=[[  3.08534969e+02   3.25666185e+03  -2.20581200e+00]
 [  3.09533447e+02   3.25965789e+03  -2.17015040e+00]
 [  3.08584658e+02   3.25954029e+03  -2.19941120e+00]
 [  3.07585711e+02   3.25667680e+03  -2.12869760e+00]
 [  3.11562101e+02   3.25982736e+03  -1.94063600e+00]
 [  3.11859006e+02   3.25702733e+03  -7.63193600e-01]
 [  3.08145280e+02   3.25572271e+03  -2.19514400e+00]
 [  3.08377680e+02   3.25856225e+03  -2.16009200e+00]
 [  3.10441338e+02   3.25829875e+03  -2.63984720e+00]
 [  3.10367962e+02   3.25389346e+03  -2.11223840e+00]
 [  3.10137910e+02   3.25741340e+03  -2.46794000e+00]
 [  3.09537281e+02   3.25892338e+03  -2.28932720e+00]
 [  3.09344406e+02   3.25543844e+03  -2.40515120e+00]
 [  3.10450645e+02   3.25749069e+03  -2.33870480e+00]
 [  3.10430410e+02   3.25851708e+03  -2.33870480e+00]
 [  3.07783327e+02   3.25704679e+03  -1.12438160e+00]
 [  3.12930506e+02   3.25741935e+03  -1.11980960e+00]
 [  3.12705650e+02   3.25455548e+03  -1.10548400e+00]
 [  3.11434863e+02   3.26262004e+03  -2.07596720e+00]
 [  3.09685407e+02   3.26189987e+03  -2.38137680e+00]
 [  3.08528861e+02   3.26162489e+03  -2.13967040e+00]
 [  3.11014726e+02   3.26106711e+03  -2.12564960e+00]
 [  3.09174753e+02   3.26233603e+03  -2.18020880e+00]
 [  3.12973636e+02   3.26208751e+03  -2.17898960e+00]
 [  3.13502547e+02   3.26047741e+03  -2.09882720e+00]
 [  3.13546812e+02   3.26050827e+03  -2.13052640e+00]
 [  3.09981100e+02   3.26250428e+03  -2.15552000e+00]
 [  3.10161877e+02   3.26164522e+03  -2.20215440e+00]
 [  3.13995539e+02   3.26372098e+03  -2.16801680e+00]
 [  3.11358342e+02   3.26370646e+03  -1.36791680e+00]
 [  3.10769621e+02   3.25945517e+03  -2.30974880e+00]
 [  3.09862741e+02   3.26403583e+03  -2.28201200e+00]
 [  3.08458161e+02   3.25817564e+03  -2.15552000e+00]
 [  3.09435541e+02   3.25825584e+03  -2.28719360e+00]
 [  3.08634345e+02   3.25732574e+03  -1.27922000e+00]
 [  3.09930506e+02   3.25441935e+03  -1.11980960e+00]
 [  3.09705650e+02   3.25755548e+03  -1.10548400e+00]
 [  3.15314631e+02   3.27539678e+03  -2.22013760e+00]
 [  3.14496076e+02   3.27450937e+03  -1.77543440e+00]
 [  3.19773285e+02   3.27483172e+03  -2.36888000e+00]
 [  3.20160936e+02   3.27174365e+03  -1.46758640e+00]
 [  3.17632108e+02   3.27333074e+03  -1.54531040e+00]
 [  3.20633806e+02   3.27121131e+03  -1.73763920e+00]
 [  3.15134081e+02   3.26918375e+03  -1.91716640e+00]
 [  3.14833043e+02   3.27344651e+03  -2.14759520e+00]
 [  3.15386873e+02   3.27457986e+03  -2.80382960e+00]
 [  3.15389504e+02   3.27056319e+03  -3.79961120e+00]
 [  3.09928864e+02   3.25862972e+03  -2.28262160e+00]
 [  3.12981100e+02   3.25850428e+03  -2.15552000e+00]
 [  3.13161877e+02   3.26164522e+03  -2.20215440e+00]
 [  3.09995539e+02   3.26272098e+03  -2.16801680e+00]
 [  3.08358342e+02   3.26470646e+03  -1.36791680e+00]
 [  3.10769621e+02   3.26145517e+03  -2.30974880e+00]
 [  3.09862741e+02   3.26403583e+03  -2.28201200e+00]
 [  3.09458161e+02   3.25917564e+03  -2.15552000e+00]
 [  3.09435541e+02   3.25825584e+03  -2.28719360e+00]
 [  3.06297341e+02   3.25738852e+03  -1.09207280e+00]
 [  3.08746854e+02   3.25800712e+03  -2.22013760e+00]
 [  3.07296526e+02   3.25420303e+03  -2.36095520e+00]
 [  3.09912102e+02   3.25860281e+03  -1.15181360e+00]
 [  3.07497596e+02   3.25625977e+03  -1.15181360e+00]
 [  3.07817203e+02   3.25477321e+03  -2.68404320e+00]
 [  3.05817919e+02   3.25780380e+03  -2.70659840e+00]
 [  3.06587855e+02   3.25373025e+03  -7.75385600e-01]
 [  3.05538448e+02   3.25854594e+03  -2.20611680e+00]
 [  3.06360464e+02   3.25706283e+03  -7.85748800e-01]
 [  3.10994093e+02   3.25396928e+03  -1.83639440e+00]
 [  3.06823412e+02   3.25784599e+03  -1.82328800e+00]
 [  3.04608725e+02   3.25721917e+03  -1.70502560e+00]
 [  3.09470284e+02   3.25645552e+03  -2.23994960e+00]
 [  3.19844699e+02   3.27955840e+03  -3.10040000e+00]
 [  3.19818319e+02   3.27689903e+03  -2.35577360e+00]
 [  3.19928996e+02   3.27901237e+03  -1.79250320e+00]
 [  3.16798820e+02   3.28194784e+03  -2.20855520e+00]
 [  3.15507571e+02   3.27824837e+03  -2.18600000e+00]
 [  3.19601448e+02   3.27198482e+03  -1.69771040e+00]
 [  3.05286609e+02   3.25691985e+03  -2.66697440e+00]
 [  3.01580345e+02   3.25622715e+03  -2.66209760e+00]
 [  3.02511985e+02   3.25794144e+03  -2.67855680e+00]
 [  3.01371515e+02   3.25342679e+03  -1.84249040e+00]
 [  3.00572376e+02   3.25445421e+03  -2.70446480e+00]
 [  3.01669594e+02   3.25676087e+03  -2.26220000e+00]
 [  3.02519127e+02   3.25346957e+03  -2.26220000e+00]
 [  3.05003400e+02   3.25737359e+03  -2.24726480e+00]
 [  3.04039856e+02   3.25785807e+03  -2.60967200e+00]
 [  3.05039933e+02   3.25685696e+03  -2.65173440e+00]
 [  3.04015052e+02   3.25476038e+03  -2.23476800e+00]
 [  3.05000290e+02   3.25470957e+03  -2.26037120e+00]
 [  3.01464646e+02   3.25791521e+03  -2.59290800e+00]
 [  3.04415035e+02   3.25351240e+03  -1.48800800e+00]
 [  3.05436737e+02   3.25702401e+03  -2.25915200e+00]
 [  3.02497966e+02   3.25370431e+03  -2.87149520e+00]
 [  3.05248617e+02   3.25693437e+03  -2.21648000e+00]
 [  3.07342867e+02   3.25343450e+03  -1.94216000e+00]
 [  3.06608725e+02   3.25721917e+03  -1.70502560e+00]
 [  3.06470284e+02   3.25445552e+03  -2.23994960e+00]]
```

The end point coordinates in x,y,z are shown below:

```
 End=[[  3.10533447e+02   3.25765789e+03  -2.27015040e+00]
 [  3.10584658e+02   3.25754029e+03  -2.29941120e+00]
 [  3.09585711e+02   3.25767680e+03  -2.22869760e+00]
 [  3.10562101e+02   3.25782736e+03  -2.04063600e+00]
 [  3.09859006e+02   3.25502733e+03  -8.63193600e-01]
 [  3.10145280e+02   3.25772271e+03  -2.29514400e+00]
 [  3.09377680e+02   3.25656225e+03  -2.26009200e+00]
 [  3.09441338e+02   3.25729875e+03  -2.73984720e+00]
 [  3.09367962e+02   3.25589346e+03  -2.21223840e+00]
 [  3.12137910e+02   3.25641340e+03  -2.56794000e+00]
 [  3.11537281e+02   3.25692338e+03  -2.38932720e+00]
 [  3.10344406e+02   3.25743844e+03  -2.50515120e+00]
 [  3.12450645e+02   3.25649069e+03  -2.43870480e+00]
 [  3.12430410e+02   3.25651708e+03  -2.43870480e+00]
 [  3.09783327e+02   3.25504679e+03  -1.22438160e+00]
 [  3.10930506e+02   3.25541935e+03  -1.21980960e+00]
 [  3.10705650e+02   3.25555548e+03  -1.20548400e+00]
 [  3.10434863e+02   3.26062004e+03  -2.17596720e+00]
 [  3.10685407e+02   3.26089987e+03  -2.48137680e+00]
 [  3.10528861e+02   3.26062489e+03  -2.23967040e+00]
 [  3.13014726e+02   3.26306711e+03  -2.22564960e+00]
 [  3.11174753e+02   3.26033603e+03  -2.28020880e+00]
 [  3.10973636e+02   3.26008751e+03  -2.27898960e+00]
 [  3.12502547e+02   3.26147741e+03  -2.19882720e+00]
 [  3.12546812e+02   3.26150827e+03  -2.23052640e+00]
 [  3.11981100e+02   3.26050428e+03  -2.25552000e+00]
 [  3.11161877e+02   3.26064522e+03  -2.30215440e+00]
 [  3.11995539e+02   3.26172098e+03  -2.26801680e+00]
 [  3.10358342e+02   3.26270646e+03  -1.46791680e+00]
 [  3.09769621e+02   3.26045517e+03  -2.40974880e+00]
 [  3.11862741e+02   3.26203583e+03  -2.38201200e+00]
 [  3.10458161e+02   3.26017564e+03  -2.25552000e+00]
 [  3.10435541e+02   3.26025584e+03  -2.38719360e+00]
 [  3.10634345e+02   3.25532574e+03  -1.37922000e+00]
 [  3.10930506e+02   3.25541935e+03  -1.21980960e+00]
 [  3.10705650e+02   3.25555548e+03  -1.20548400e+00]
 [  3.17314631e+02   3.27439678e+03  -2.32013760e+00]
 [  3.16496076e+02   3.27350937e+03  -1.87543440e+00]
 [  3.18773285e+02   3.27683172e+03  -2.46888000e+00]
 [  3.18160936e+02   3.27274365e+03  -1.56758640e+00]
 [  3.15632108e+02   3.27233074e+03  -1.64531040e+00]
 [  3.18633806e+02   3.27221131e+03  -1.83763920e+00]
 [  3.17134081e+02   3.27118375e+03  -2.01716640e+00]
 [  3.16833043e+02   3.27144651e+03  -2.24759520e+00]
 [  3.13386873e+02   3.27257986e+03  -2.90382960e+00]
 [  3.13389504e+02   3.27256319e+03  -3.89961120e+00]
 [  3.10928864e+02   3.26062972e+03  -2.38262160e+00]
 [  3.11981100e+02   3.26050428e+03  -2.25552000e+00]
 [  3.11161877e+02   3.26064522e+03  -2.30215440e+00]
 [  3.11995539e+02   3.26172098e+03  -2.26801680e+00]
 [  3.10358342e+02   3.26270646e+03  -1.46791680e+00]
 [  3.09769621e+02   3.26045517e+03  -2.40974880e+00]
 [  3.11862741e+02   3.26203583e+03  -2.38201200e+00]
 [  3.10458161e+02   3.26017564e+03  -2.25552000e+00]
 [  3.10435541e+02   3.26025584e+03  -2.38719360e+00]
 [  3.07297341e+02   3.25538852e+03  -1.19207280e+00]
 [  3.06746854e+02   3.25700712e+03  -2.32013760e+00]
 [  3.08296526e+02   3.25520303e+03  -2.46095520e+00]
 [  3.08912102e+02   3.25660281e+03  -1.25181360e+00]
 [  3.05497596e+02   3.25525977e+03  -1.25181360e+00]
 [  3.06817203e+02   3.25677321e+03  -2.78404320e+00]
 [  3.06817919e+02   3.25680380e+03  -2.80659840e+00]
 [  3.07587855e+02   3.25573025e+03  -8.75385600e-01]
 [  3.07538448e+02   3.25654594e+03  -2.30611680e+00]
 [  3.07360464e+02   3.25606283e+03  -8.85748800e-01]
 [  3.08994093e+02   3.25596928e+03  -1.93639440e+00]
 [  3.08823412e+02   3.25584599e+03  -1.92328800e+00]
 [  3.05608725e+02   3.25521917e+03  -1.80502560e+00]
 [  3.08470284e+02   3.25545552e+03  -2.33994960e+00]
 [  3.17844699e+02   3.28055840e+03  -3.20040000e+00]
 [  3.18818319e+02   3.27789903e+03  -2.45577360e+00]
 [  3.17928996e+02   3.28001237e+03  -1.89250320e+00]
 [  3.18798820e+02   3.27994784e+03  -2.30855520e+00]
 [  3.17507571e+02   3.28024837e+03  -2.28600000e+00]
 [  3.17601448e+02   3.27398482e+03  -1.79771040e+00]
 [  3.03286609e+02   3.25591985e+03  -2.76697440e+00]
 [  3.03580345e+02   3.25522715e+03  -2.76209760e+00]
 [  3.03511985e+02   3.25594144e+03  -2.77855680e+00]
 [  3.03371515e+02   3.25542679e+03  -1.94249040e+00]
 [  3.01572376e+02   3.25545421e+03  -2.80446480e+00]
 [  3.03669594e+02   3.25576087e+03  -2.36220000e+00]
 [  3.03519127e+02   3.25546957e+03  -2.36220000e+00]
 [  3.04003400e+02   3.25537359e+03  -2.34726480e+00]
 [  3.03039856e+02   3.25585807e+03  -2.70967200e+00]
 [  3.03039933e+02   3.25585696e+03  -2.75173440e+00]
 [  3.03015052e+02   3.25576038e+03  -2.33476800e+00]
 [  3.04000290e+02   3.25570957e+03  -2.36037120e+00]
 [  3.03464646e+02   3.25591521e+03  -2.69290800e+00]
 [  3.03415035e+02   3.25551240e+03  -1.58800800e+00]
 [  3.03436737e+02   3.25602401e+03  -2.35915200e+00]
 [  3.03497966e+02   3.25570431e+03  -2.97149520e+00]
 [  3.03248617e+02   3.25593437e+03  -2.31648000e+00]
 [  3.08342867e+02   3.25543450e+03  -2.04216000e+00]
 [  3.05608725e+02   3.25521917e+03  -1.80502560e+00]
 [  3.08470284e+02   3.25545552e+03  -2.33994960e+00]]
```

My attempted code is shown below:

```
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  numberOfLines = len(Start)
  approximateLinesPerCentroid = (numberOfLines/10) +1
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=approximateLinesPerCentroid, random_state=0).fit(Start)
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  for n in range(approximateLinesPerCentroid): 
     kmeans.cluster_centers_[n][2]=0
  for n in range(approximateLinesPerCentroid):
    ax.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[n][0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[n][1], kmeans.cluster_centers_[n][2],color='green', marker='^',s=60)
  for line in range(numberOfLines):
    ax.plot([Start[line][0],End[line][0]], [Start[line][1],End[line][1]], [Start[line][2],End[line][2]], color='grey')
  ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
  ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
  ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
  for line in range(numberOfLines):
      centroid = kmeans.labels_[line]        
      CentroidToLabelMap[centroid].append(line)
  print CentroidToLabelMap
  plt.show()
```

Attached are pictures showing the solution of my attempted code: [Side View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9X66.png)

[Top View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayAYK.png)

The CentroidToLabelMap in the code is defined as the assignment of each line to the centroid in a list of a list format. Each list represents the lines attach to its centroid. As can be seen, some centroids take more than 10 lines.

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 75], [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92], [21, 24, 25, 28, 29, 31, 50, 51, 53], [5, 15, 16, 17, 34, 35, 36], [39, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74], [56, 57, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 94], [18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 26, 27, 30, 32, 33, 47, 48, 49, 52, 54, 55], [45, 46], [7, 9, 58, 59, 66, 67, 69, 93, 95]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular KMeans doesn't work like this. No guarantees or restrictions could be made on the number of points in each cluster. [See this relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950670/how-to-cluster-with-k-means-when-number-of-clusters-and-their-sizes-are-known)

However, there is a "variation" that can work in that way. [See this](https://github.com/ndanielsen/Same-Size-K-Means). I didn't try it before though.
To the best of my knowledge, no scikit-learn algorithm can do this off the shelf.